# A simple way to add pipes to tee-d file

Tags: shell, named-pipes, tee

I'm trying to record the output of a command with post processing to clean things up
(like removing ansi escape codes to a file while outputing the command to screen)
(command is minicom which functions as a terminal among other things).
currently I have the following but it doesn't work(seems to block).

```
rm "${fifo}"
mkfifo "${fifo}"
cat "${fifo}"|filter_1 >"${log_file}" &
command |tee "${fifo}"
```

p.s.

```
command | tee "${log_file}"
```

works fine

Comment: see if your system has the `unbuffer` command available. You may have to experiment to see which of your producing commands have to be `unbuffered`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Besides `unbuffer`, you can try

```
{ command ; printf "\n" ; } | tee "${log_file}"
```

I hope this helps.